# How is the gravitational force different between both?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity

How would the results for gravitational force between two masses differ if we have two masses with larger and unequal values compared to having the same mass for both. How is the gravitational force different between both?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify @Drjh's answer, even if the total mass stays the same the force will vary.

Look again at the equation $$F = G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}$$

It uses the products of the 2 masses. However, the total mass uses the sum of them. Different arithmetic operations produce different results.

Assume we start with $m_1=1$ and $m_2=1$. In that case the total mass is $m_1+m_2=2$ and the force is proportional to $m_1m_2=1$. Now change masses so $m_1=.5$ and $m_2=1.5$. In that case the total mass is still $2$, but the product of the 2 masses is only $1.5\times0.5=0.75$.

For different scenarios, change the values of $m_1$ and $m_2$ and see how the force equation changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what would happen just by looking at this equation

$$F = G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}$$

which describes this force.

So what happens if the masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ are varied the way you describe?

Obviously if the masses are equal, say $m$, you will get a term $m^2$ and if you have another two masses both larger than $m$, say $M_1$ and $M_2$, then $m^2 \lt M_1 M_2$. So that the force will be smaller in the first case as compared to the latter case.